# Did prophet Muhammad saw ever give in to his anger?

Tags: practical-islam

I know this is probably a very stupid question but today something happened with me and I was raging with anger and told myself, "Calm down your prophet never gave in to his anger". But then I realized what if it wasn't true I mean he was a human. If anyone could explain sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple ahadith which indicate the Prophet became angry.  However, precisely how angry, and for how long, is probably difficult to ascertain.

> Narrated Abu Musa Al-Ash'ari: **Allah's Messenger was asked about things which he disliked, and when the people asked too many questions, he became angry and said, "Ask me (any question)."** A man got up and said, "O Allah's Apostle! Who is my father?" The Prophet replied, "Your father is Hudhaifa." Then another man got up and said, "O Allah's Messenger! Who is my father?" The Prophet said, "Your father is Salim, Maula Shaiba." When `Umar saw the signs of anger on the face of Allah's Messenger, he said, "We repent to Allah."
> <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 7291](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/96/22)</sub>
>
> Narrated `Abdullah: The Prophet divided and distributed something as he used to do for some of his distributions. A man from the Ansar said, "By Allah, in this division the pleasure of Allah has not been intended." I said, "I will definitely tell this to the Prophet." So I went to him while he was sitting with his companions and told him of it secretly. That was hard upon the Prophet and the color of his face changed, and **he became so angry that I wished I had not told him**. The Prophet then said, "Moses was harmed with more than this, yet he remained patient."
> <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 6100](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/127)</sub>
>
> Ibn ‘Umar reported: One day while the Messenger of Allah was giving sermon **he suddenly saw phlegm on the wall towards the qiblah (the direction to which Muslims turn in prayer) of the mosque. So he became angry at people.** He then scraped it and sent for saffron and stained with it. He then said: When any one of you prays, Allah, the Exalted, faces him: he, therefore, should not spit before him.
> <sub>[Sunan Abi Dawud 479](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/89) [grade: sahih]</sub>
>
> Narrated 'Aisha: Whenever Allah's Messenger ordered the Muslims to do something, he used to order them deeds which were easy for them to do, (according to their strength and endurance). They said, "O Allah's Messenger! We are not like you. Allah has forgiven your past and future sins." So **Allah's Apostle became angry and it was apparent on his face. He said, "I am the most Allah fearing, and know Allah better than all of you do."**
> <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 20](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/13)</sub>

Other examples are: [Sunan Abi Dawud 2182](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/13/8), [Sahih al-Bukhari 2359](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/42/8), [Sahih al-Bukhari 6112](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/139), [Sunan Abi Dawud 2700](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/15/224), [Sahih al-Bukhari 7139](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/93/3).